# 240V power plug, only getting 120v, and 97v?

Tags: electrical, 240v, 120-240v

This is the plug/socket:

[image]

Between one line and neutral, I get 120v. Between the other line and neutral, I get nothing. However, when I go between the line and the line, I get 97 volts. (I'm testing this at the end of a wire hooked to my drier, the prongs on my multimeter won't go that deep.)

Also, [this](http://i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/dce07b8c-a054/k2-_4b5c7fa2-3ef4-462e-9365-f3861f31f4ed.v1.jpg) is my multimeter and I tried on the 200 and 600 range on the top left quadrant of the circle. I am also in the last 2 ports (left to right).

Edit: I did check continuity between the prongs and the ends of the wires, everything checks out.

Comment: *Cross-post from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/electricians/comments/3jrueo/240v_power_plug_only_getting_120v_and_97v/)

Answer (score 2):

You have one open hot leg. You are getting the 97 volts because you are checking from a live hot to one with a load on it and you are reading through the load, which is why you are getting a weird reading.